# What are the best way to manage "standalone" and app store version of applications?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

I need to maintain in parallel two version of the same applications. One for app store and one  standalone (not app store) version.

My initial plan was to use the master branch for developing all feature that are common for both version. For standalone version my plan was to create a new branch, and in that branch to add a features for standalone applications, and the same for app store version.

Actually I tried my plan, but I have a problem with cocoapods. I have multiple dependencies that are common, but for standalone application I need to use a Sparkle framework. Now every time I try to merge master to one of my branches I have a huge conflicts with cocoapods files. That are very difficult to solve. 
I was thinking about removing pods for my source control but than, when I switch branches I will need to do "pod install" every time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use Targets.
Look [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) and [here](http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code).